# get introduced vs getting introduced

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

What is difference between "get introduced" and "getting introduced"?
Is "getting introduced" some form of perfect participle?
e.g.
When first getting introduced, make sure to make direct eye contact....
Getting Introduced to Dark Side....

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-continuous

Answer (score 1):

> **When first getting introduced**, make sure to make direct eye contact.

The highlighted part of this sentence is an adverbial that contains the [participle phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) **getting introduced**. In this case, the adverbial specifies when something happened. Participle phrases do not include a verb. here are some more examples:

> **Walking on the beach**, we found lots of nice shells.
>   **When sunbathng**, apply sunscreen at regular intervals

Your second example is not a complete sentence, so it's difficult to say how it is composed grammatically. Here are two (slightly adapted) possibilities...

> **Getting introduced to my girlfriend's parents yesterday**, I noticed that her mother's eyes looked exactly like hers. - *adverbial containing participle*
>
> **Getting introduced to my girlfriend's parents yesterday** was very stressful. - *gerund phrase, which acts as a noun and is the subject of **was***

**get introduced** is present simple. You could use it like this:

> When you first **get introduced**, make sure to make direct eye contact.

Note that, when you use **get** in present simple, it requires a subject. In this example, the subject is **you**.

Both the original (participle-phrase) sentence and this present simple sentence are grammatically correct. The present simple version is probably easier to understand, especially for non-native speakers, but native speakers would probably feel that the participle-phrase version is more stylish.

Answer (score -1):

Difference is in the form of the verb.

**Getting** is in present continuous.

**Get or Gets (for he she it)** is in present continuous.

You would have many opportunities to use both of them in a context. Look for what is one or other form used. It's quite a list and easy to google, I will not copy paste it here.

Here is just 2 quick examples:

- I always get introduced to a lot of people at parties.  **Present
  simple** used for something that always happens.
- I am getting introduced for the 3rd time today to the same person.
  **Present continuous** being used to express something that is happening
  this very moment.

**EDIT** - explanation for comment:

For me sentence would be way better off if written like:

> When you are getting introduced to someone for the first time, make sure that you maintain direct eye contact.

Let's get back to original one:

> When first getting introduced, make sure to make direct eye contact.

It's present continuous being used when talking about the future. It's one of it's uses. It's awkward since it's named present I know but It is legit. 
You use it to make a question about future like:

What are you doing next week?

Or state that while something happening in future, like it's currently, emphasize "at that moment where it's happening". Notice how by it you know that in that moment rest of the sentence is happening. like:

When being attacked, you should defend yourself.

In same way the reference of when you will be introduced is in future but we are gonna use present continuous to emphasize that at THAT very moment you, while it's happening you should remain eye contact.

Comment: it's confusing me that in sentence >When first getting introduced, make sure to make direct eye contact< is missing present tense of the verb be

Comment: It is not present continuous: it is a participle phrase.